# How to read attribute "name" of my json array in Ionic

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, ionic3

[json array localstorage format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHNMc.jpg)

Hello, I'm developing an ionic app. I'm new in Ionic and Typescript.

As you can see in the image below I'm parsing from an API my data in a json array.

On ts file I'm writing this code

`
public categoryDetails:any;

const datacat = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('categoryData'));
    this.categoryDetails = datacat.categoryData;`

And in my html file when I write this

`<h1 class="business-top">Business of the category {{categoryDetails.name}}</h1>`

I get the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

I know that I don't read the attribute "name" correctly. How can I do this one?

Moreover, how can I display Businesses which associate with the spesific term_id of the category?

Answer (score 0):

In this example you need to do that

```
<h1 class="business-top">Business of the category {{categoryDetails?.name}}</h1>

public categoryDetails: any;

this.categoryDetails = localStorage.getItem('categoryData');
```

or you can use ionic storage. it is better if you are using ionic.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
public categoryDetails: any;
  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  ...

  // set a key/value
  storage.set('categoryData', 'Max');

  // Or to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('categoryData').then((val) => {
    this.categoryDetails = val;
  });
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't work. A blank field, where category name should be shown, appears. About the second one, my whole app has been based on localStorage. I fetch my data from Mysql DB as Json arrays. As you can see in the attached photo the userData can be read pretty well with `const datacat = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('categoryData')); this.categoryDetails = datacat.categoryData;`. But all other Json that are in arrays can't be read with the same method? How can I read attributes from businessData & CategoryData?

Answer (score 0):

I finally fingured it out.

@Kilomat thanks for your help and your advice about using ionic storage. That saved me from futured problems.

About my json file that's what I did.

In my HTML code
`<ion-grid no-margin>
    <h1 class="business-top">Επιχειρήσεις της κατηγορίας {{businessData.name}} {{businessData.term_id}}</h1>
    <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="col col-50" *ngFor="let c of BusinessCategoryDetails" text-wrap (click)="product(c)">
      <div *ngIf="c.term_id == businessData.term_id">
      <h2>{{c.post_title}} {{c.term_id}}</h2> <img width="80" height="80" src="{{c.guid}}">
      </div>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-grid>`

And in my TS code
`var businessCategory: categories = navParams.get("businessCategory");
    console.log(businessCategory); /*exports the Selected category*/

```
var newData = JSON.stringify(businessCategory);
this.businessData = JSON.parse(newData);`
```

Which takes properties and values from my previous category page. TS code

`categories: [categoryDetails] = null;

gotobusiness(category: categories){
    this.navCtrl.push(BusinessPage, { businessCategory: category});
  }`